# EF Core and an encapsulated collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to follow the advice here: https://ardalis.com/encapsulated-collections-in-entity-framework-core

I have a class, which looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    private readonly List<PersonSport> _entries = new List<PersonSport>();
    public IEnumerable<PersonSport> Entries => _entries.AsReadOnly();

    public void AddEntry(PersonSport entry)
    {
        _entries.Add(entry);
    }
}
```

and a dbcontext, which looks like this:

```
public class PersonSportContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sport> Sport{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSport>().HasKey(sc => new { sc.PersonId, sc.SportId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sport>()
       .ToTable("Sport")
       .HasDiscriminator<string>("SportType")
       .HasValue<Football>("Football")
       .HasValue<Running>("Running");

        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSport>()
            .HasOne<Person>(sc => sc.Person)
            .WithMany(s => s.PersonSport)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.PersonId);


        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSport>()
            .HasOne<Sport>(sc => sc.Sport)
            .WithMany(s => s.PersonSport)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.SportId);

        var navigation = modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(ConsoleApp1.Person.PersonSport));
        navigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=PersonSport;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }
```

I see a compilation error:

> "DbSet does not contain a definition for Entries".

I have highlighted the line that errors using a comment ('Entries' is underlined in red due to the compilation error).  I have spent hours Googling this and have got nowhere.  What am I doing wrong please?

**Update**
cwharris's answer has helped with the compilation error.  It now runs.  I have created a Console app to test it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PersonSportContext personSportContext = new PersonSportContext();
            var person = personSportContext.Person.Include(t => t.PersonSport).FirstOrDefault(); 
            var sport = personSportContext.Sport.Include(t => t.PersonSport).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        }
```

Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Notice that Person.PersonSport.Sport is null.  Now see the below (when I stop the debugger on the following line):

[image]

Notice that Person.PersonSport.Sport is not null anymore.

Why is this? How can I ensure that Person.PersonSport.Sport  is opulated when I populate the Person variable?

Comment: verify that all your reference assemblies are compiled correctly because `Entires` != `Entries`.

Comment: Just making sure, the `Entires` vs `Entries` typo isn't the issue here, right?

Comment: @Progman, I have edited the paragraph of text you refer to.

Comment: @cwharris, please see my comment directly above.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to *right click the Person* and *go to definition*  to see if the Person is the one we are talking about?

Comment: @w0051977 You `Include()` statement loads only that exact navigation property. In this case it will load `Person.PersonSport` but not `Person.PersonSport.Sport`. You can add additional `Include()` statements to load additional navigation properties. However, this is now a different question/problem.

Comment: The advice you are following IMHO is totally wrong. EF entities represent a storage model, hence should not apply DDD or OOP principles. Keep them simple POCOs with public auto get/set properties and you'll have no issues.

Comment: @Progman, why does loading sport on the line below (see second screenshot) also load Person.PersonSport.Sport? Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, are you saying the domain model should be completely isolated? I e separate to the data model?

Comment: @w0051977 Entity Framework is smart. It recognize its the same Id so it updates the reference in your other object with the same object, but you actually load it only when you execute the second line. Before that it's not in the context `personSportContext`, so the navigation property is `null`.

Comment: @Portman, can you provide an answer showing how to load it on the first line? I will then give some credit.

Comment: Based on my experience with EF6 / Core, yes. Separate domain, store, DTO / View  etc. models with mapping between where needed helps avoiding serialization and design issues due to different requirements / rules.

Comment: @w0051977 You add an additional `Include()` call (you can chain them): `.Include(t => t.PersonSport.Select(t2 => t2.Sport))`

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, that is very interesting in deed.  I even asked a question about it at the end of last year: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363001/separating-the-domain-model-from-the-data-model.  Do you know any practical examples e.g. open source where the domain model is completely isolated and separated from the data model?

Comment: But anyway, if you want to follow such advices, it's up to you. I see that your original problem is solved, so probably you should accept the answer that helped solving it. What about the post update, it's a different (and unrelated) issue which has an explanation, but should be asked in a separate question. Or take a look at `ThenInclude` in [Including multiple levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) topic. Also note the [Eager loading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) Tip as of why the property is not null anymore.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, agreed.  I have marked the answer.  If you would like to answer my other question (see link in last comment), then I would be grateful for your thoughts; particularly if you are experienced separating the data model and domain model.  The only example I could find at the time was this one: https://github.com/sapiens/ModernMembership/blob/master/src/ModernMembership/LocalMember.cs, which uses the Memento pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `nameof(Person.Entries)` is intended to reference the `Person` class, but is in fact looking at the `Person` property of the `PersonSportContext` class, due to a lack of name-spacing. Try prepending the `Person` class namespace within the `nameof` operator.

```
nameof(Person.Entries)
```

should become

```
nameof(MyNamespaceWherePersonClassResides.Person.Entries)
```

Comment: I believe that is what I have done on the line that errors (as per the instructions in the link).  Could you tell me what that line of code should be replaced with? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example of what needs to be changed.

Comment: Could you have a look at my edit before I mark your answer? I am not quite there yet.  +1 for the edit.